# How to save checked values in session and show it on other page

Tags: php, checkbox, session-variables

I have a table. In each line there is a checkbox.
I want that if a user checks any line the value stock gets stored in `$_SESSION` so I can use it in other page to show it there. 
*(Just to test to make sure  that it works)*

First page:

```
<?php
$Police = $_SESSION['N_Police'];

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM facture WHERE Client='.$Police;  
$lst = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<?php
     while ($fact = mysql_fetch_array($lst))
     {
        ?>

            <?php if (strcmp(($fact['Etat']),("Payé"))) { ?>
                    <tr style="background:White;">
            <?php } else if (strcmp(($fact['Etat']),("Non Payé"))) { ?>
                    <tr style="background:#FFCC77;">
            <?php } ?>
                    <td width="5%"> <form method="post"><input Type="checkbox" name="cle[]" Value="<?php $fact['NumFacture']; ?>"></form></td>
                    <td>  <?php echo $fact['NumFacture']; ?>  </td>
                    <td>  <?php echo $fact['Mois'].'-'.$fact['Annee']; ?>  </td>
                    <td>  <?php echo $fact['Montant']; ?>  </td>
                    <td>  <?php echo $fact['Dernier delai']; ?>  </td>
                    <td>  <?php echo $fact['Etat']; ?>  </td>
                </tr>

            <?php
                }
                mysql_free_result($lst);
                mysql_close();
            ?>
```

and I use this code to save on the same page:

```
<?php 
     if (isset($_POST["cle"])){
         foreach ($_POST["cle"] as $key => $value){
            $_SESSION["cle"] = $_POST["cle"];
         }
    }
?>
```

And in the other page I'm trying to show it like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION["cle"])) {
         foreach ($_SESSION["cle"] as  $key => $value)
             echo "<b>Your games are: </b>"  . $value;
    }
?>
```

But this doesn't work. So my question is: How do I show the stock value from the checked items on the first page on the second page by using `$_SESSION`?

Comment: As an aside, you should really change from using `mysql_` to using `mysqli_`. `mysql_` functions are deprecated. Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, consider passing `$Police` through `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or better yet, look into using prepared statements.

Comment: You didn't submit your form. how can the data be saved?

Comment: thanks for the advice, I will change it, but for the moment it works I need solution for my problem , Thanks Kevin

Comment: Zairwolf, I want to be saved just by cheking, is it possible ?

Comment: @Younes, just for confirmation, did you close the form tag used on that page?

Comment: `name="cle[0]"` - remove single quote. `$_SESSION['cle'] = $value;` in the foreach loop. Also `echo "<b>Your games are: </b>"  . $value;` in the 2nd one.

Comment: @Siva.G I think yes !

Comment: @Deadooshka I made some modification but didn t work look into my code

Comment: @Younes Check with open the `form` tag before the `<table>` tag and end the `form` tag after `</table>`.

Comment: missed echo here `Value="<?php echo $fact['NumFacture']; ?>"`. Remove form tags near each checkbox, since one form tag must include all your checkboxes. Can't understand `$_SESSION["cle"] = $_POST["cle"];` in the 1st foreach.

Comment: @Siva.G it s all oké !

Comment: I m waiting for help

Answer (score 1):

I think You can achieve that feature you are looking for through `AJAX`.

First of all keep some `id` attribute in tour `checkbox`.

```
<td width="5%">
 <form method="post"><input id='number' Type="checkbox" name="cle[]" Value="<?php $fact['NumFacture']; ?>">
</form>
</td>
```

Then from jQuery you can do like this

```
   $('#number').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
          var value = $(this).val();
          $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "<?php echo your_php_file_url ?>",
          data: {datas: value},
          dataType: 'html'
        });
        }
    });
```

Then from your `php` file, insert the data into `SESSION`

You can get the data using `$_POST['datas']`.